# Problem making an Android app with BeeWare

Tags: java, android, android-studio, voc, beeware

I tried making an android app with BeeWare following the guides. The app it's just the plain template so I didn't do any modifications to it, but since my first try I was getting countless of exceptions which I was able to resolve looking up for solutions, except this last one that I tried to look up for a fix as I did for the previous one but none of the possible solution I found worked.

I tried launching it from the bash of Visual Code with the Python virtual environment and also with Android Studio, same results...

Console error log:

```
:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug FAILED
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Java\Visual Basic Code\source\mirror 4.0\ABSOLUTE5\HomeTheater\android\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\0
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:593)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:720)
    at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForTasksWithQuickFail(WaitableExecutor.java:146)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.transform(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:306)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:221)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:217)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:212)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:97)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBuildCacheKeyExecuter.execute(ResolveBuildCacheKeyExecuter.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:97)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:596)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Java\Visual Basic Code\source\mirror 4.0\ABSOLUTE5\HomeTheater\android\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\0
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.launchProcessing(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:803)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.lambda$convertToDexArchive$8(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:728)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing.
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:169)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.convert(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:146)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.launchProcessing(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:798)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:598)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.get(ForkJoinTask.java:1005)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ThreadUtils.awaitFutures(ThreadUtils.java:21)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.IRConverter.convertClassesToDex(IRConverter.java:315)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.IRConverter.convertToDex(IRConverter.java:225)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.optimize(D8.java:187)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:158)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.lambda$run$1(D8.java:91)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:58)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withD8CompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:45)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:88)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.convert(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:144)
    ... 7 more
    Suppressed: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.get(ForkJoinTask.java:1006)
        ... 17 more
    [CIRCULAR REFERENCE:java.lang.NullPointerException]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.JarState.readLocal(JarState.java:556)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.JarSourceCode.updateState(JarSourceCode.java:1609)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.JarSourceCode.updateState(JarSourceCode.java:1125)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.JarSourceCode.computeBlockEntryJarStates(JarSourceCode.java:442)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.JarSourceCode.buildPrelude(JarSourceCode.java:366)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.IRBuilder.build(IRBuilder.java:362)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.JarCode.internalBuild(JarCode.java:149)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.JarCode.internalBuildWithLocals(JarCode.java:126)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.JarCode.buildIR(JarCode.java:101)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.DexEncodedMethod.buildIR(DexEncodedMethod.java:221)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.IRConverter.rewriteCode(IRConverter.java:516)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.IRConverter.convertMethodToDex(IRConverter.java:324)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.DexClass.forEachMethodThrowing(DexClass.java:133)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.IRConverter.lambda$convertClassesToDex$2(IRConverter.java:311)
    ... 5 more
```

my 'build.gradle'

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
    }
}

task buildPythonDebug << {
    exec {
        commandLine "voc -v -p app -o build/intermediates/classes/debug app".split()
    }
    exec {
        commandLine "voc -v -p app_packages -o build/intermediates/classes/debug app_packages".split()
    }
}

task buildPythonRelease << {
    exec {
        commandLine "voc -v -p app -o build/intermediates/classes/release app".split()
    }
    exec {
        commandLine "voc -v -p app_packages -o build/intermediates/classes/release app_packages".split()
    }
}

task run << {
    exec {
        commandLine "adb shell am start -n com.homesmart.HomeTheater/android.Saibbo".split()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }
}

project.afterEvaluate {
    packageDebug.dependsOn buildPythonDebug
    packageRelease.dependsOn buildPythonRelease
    run.dependsOn installDebug
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
}

repositories {
    google()
}
```

more details

```
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Java\Visual Basic Code\source\mirror 4.0\ABSOLUTE5\HomeTheater\android\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\0
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Java\Visual Basic Code\source\mirror 4.0\ABSOLUTE5\HomeTheater\android\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\0
  > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Java\Visual Basic Code\source\mirror 4.0\ABSOLUTE5\HomeTheater\android\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\0
    > Failed to process C:\Java\Visual Basic Code\source\mirror 4.0\ABSOLUTE5\HomeTheater\android\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\0
      > Error while dexing.
        > (No message provided)
          > (No message provided)






org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.Open stacktrace
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Java\Visual Basic Code\source\mirror 4.0\ABSOLUTE5\HomeTheater\android\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\0Open stacktrace
Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Java\Visual Basic Code\source\mirror 4.0\ABSOLUTE5\HomeTheater\android\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\0Open stacktrace
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Java\Visual Basic Code\source\mirror 4.0\ABSOLUTE5\HomeTheater\android\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\0Open stacktrace
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Java\Visual Basic Code\source\mirror 4.0\ABSOLUTE5\HomeTheater\android\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\0Open stacktrace
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing.Open stacktrace
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: (No message provided)Open stacktrace
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: (No message provided)Close stacktrace
at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.JarState.readLocal(JarState.java:556)
at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.JarSourceCode.updateState(JarSourceCode.java:1609)
at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.JarSourceCode.updateState(JarSourceCode.java:1125)
at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.JarSourceCode.computeBlockEntryJarStates(JarSourceCode.java:442)
at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.JarSourceCode.buildPrelude(JarSourceCode.java:366)
at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.IRBuilder.build(IRBuilder.java:362)
at com.android.tools.r8.graph.JarCode.internalBuild(JarCode.java:149)
at com.android.tools.r8.graph.JarCode.internalBuildWithLocals(JarCode.java:126)
at com.android.tools.r8.graph.JarCode.buildIR(JarCode.java:101)
at com.android.tools.r8.graph.DexEncodedMethod.buildIR(DexEncodedMethod.java:221)
at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.IRConverter.rewriteCode(IRConverter.java:516)
at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.IRConverter.convertMethodToDex(IRConverter.java:324)
at com.android.tools.r8.graph.DexClass.forEachMethodThrowing(DexClass.java:133)
at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.IRConverter.lambda$convertClassesToDex$2(IRConverter.java:311)
```

> Gradle 4.7, Build scan plugin 1.13, Android Gradle plugin 3.1.1

Comment: You are getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException` - is this happening on your code?

Comment: I think it's something with dexing a file in build `Failed to process ...\android\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\0`

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the beeware's android support is just broken, only fix is to wait for a fix I think.

Comment: As far as I can see you are using version 3.1.1 of Android Studio. That is quite an old version, so I suggest that you switch to 3.4.1, to see if the same issue is still present. If it is could you perhaps open an issue on https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=317603? Then the d8 compiler team will take a look.

Comment: I'll try to update it. I checked with beeware's irc chat and it's already a known issue, that's where I found it

Comment: Thanks for checking with beeware - did they have an open issue on this?

Comment: https://twitter.com/PyBeeWare/status/1092396371250864128 Also there are plenty open issue about this on github